# Error with the render method when I run the component

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get the component to work, so I just want to do a login on my app.

I'm using reqres.in API

The error is "Invariant Violation: element type is invalid...
check the render method of SignIn"

I've only value params on render method with Input and Button this.state.email, this.state.email and this.handleSignInPress

Here is the code on github:

http://github.com/jairolima/simple-auth-rn

Comment: Where is your render method?
React Class Component needs a render method to show it's content and it should return what you need to render, it is a must that you understand how React works, and React way thinking.

Comment: It's because I can't post full code here, anyway you can check on github here: https://github.com/jairolima/simple-auth-rn

Comment: AH right, gonna check.